# Sum the amount by checking more than 2 values in a record

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Emp>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>1</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>100.00</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>1</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>5000</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>2</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>200.00</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>3</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>500</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
</Emp>
```

Target xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Emp>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM1</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>1</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>5100.00</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>2</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>200.00</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
    <EmpDetail>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Project</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>PROJ2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <ProjectDetails>
            <Code>Element</Code>
            <ProjectReference>
                <Reference>
                    <RefCode>ELEM2</RefCode>
                </Reference>
            </ProjectReference>
        </ProjectDetails>
        <Period>
            <PeriodNo>3</PeriodNo>
        </Period>
        <AmountDetails>
            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
            <Amount>
                <Value>500</Value>
            </Amount>
        </AmountDetails>
    </EmpDetail>
</Emp>
```

Query: If the PeriodNo, Project's RefCode and Element's RefCode are same then I have to sum the amount value and should generate only one record. In my source file, the first two line item's periodno, project's refcode and element's refcode are same, so would like to get only one record in the output and the amount value should be (100+5000) = 5100.

I have idea if I have to check for one value and do the sum of the lineitem, but in this case I have to check 3 values in each record and I have sum it. Could you please tell me, how to proceed with it using xslt. I have XSLT 1.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you already find a solution at this point, but because there is no solution posted here I am posting mine which is based in Muenchian Grouping.

I have tried to explain the code using comments, hope it helps.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Copy by default attributes, elements and text -->    
    <xsl:template match="*|@*">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Key which is going to allow us to identify each EmpDetail by the
         following id (which is a string): ProjectRefCode-ElementRefCode-PeriodNo

         Using the key function we are going to be able to select the set of
         EmpDetail nodes which have the described structure. So elements with
         the same id (i.e. same ProjectRefCode, ElementRefCode and PeriodNo)
         are going to be matched using: key('detail-key', $id), where $id holds
         the id to be matched. -->
    <xsl:key name="detail-key"
             match="Emp/EmpDetail"
             use="concat(ProjectDetails[Code = 'Project']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                         ProjectDetails[Code = 'Element']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                         Period/PeriodNo)" />

    <xsl:template match="Emp">

        <!-- Copy the current node and process its children EmpDetail elements -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- We use key('detail-key', $id)[1] where the $id is the concat
                 expression to select one element per group, i.e. we iterate
                 over a set of unique EmpDetail elements -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="EmpDetail[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('detail-key',
                                               concat(ProjectDetails[Code = 'Project']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                                               ProjectDetails[Code = 'Element']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                                               Period/PeriodNo))[1])]" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- When the Value element is found, we perform the sum of all the Value elements
         which are contained in the group matched by the id described above-->
    <xsl:template match="Value">

        <!-- Cache parent node to avoid repeated operations -->
        <xsl:variable name="current-detail"
                      select="../../.." />

        <!-- Generate the id for the current EmpDetail element as described
             above -->
        <xsl:variable name="detail-id"
                      select="concat($current-detail/ProjectDetails[Code = 'Project']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                                     $current-detail/ProjectDetails[Code = 'Element']/ProjectReference/Reference/RefCode, '-',
                                     $current-detail/Period/PeriodNo)" />

        <!-- Wrap the sum with the Value element -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- We use the key function to fetch all the EmpDetail elements with the
             same id as the current one and sum them -->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('detail-key', $detail-id)/AmountDetails/Amount/Value)" />
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```